# How to get the OpenSSL version in a Tomcat 6 installation

Tags: openssl, heartbleed

After reading an [article about the Heartbleed security bug](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Security/Heartbleed), I understand that it is good practice to check the OpenSSL version Apache Tomcat is using.

The article contains this sentence:

> **What version of OpenSSL is Tomcat using?**
>
> This information is logged by AprLifecycleListener when Tomcat starts. For example,
>
> ```
> 10-Apr-2014 19:25:28.801 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.30 using APR version 1.4.8.
> 10-Apr-2014 19:25:28.804 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
> 10-Apr-2014 19:25:29.955 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014)
> ```

I spent a couple of hours searching but can't find this information in the Tomcat logs. Is there another place where I should look? Is there another way to figure this out?

I'm using Tomcat 6 on Windows Server 2003. I tried to change the log level to `Info`, and then to `Debug`, each time restarting the web server, to no avail.

Comment: are you sure you use the https-connector?

Comment: How can I check it? I'm completely newbye to Tomcat's world, I usually work with IIS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenSSL is not part of Tomcat. It's a seperate application. You don't need OpenSSL to use Tomcat. OpenSSL is used for SSL on Unix and Linux systems. Windows has its own SSL implementation, but you can install openssl on Windows as well.

Do you use SSL for Tomcat? So do you connect to the tomcat webapp using something like `https://localhost:8443` or do you have IIS or Apache inbetween? The log example you quote is an example!

If you have Openssl installed, you can find the version by following these steps:

- Click the Windows "Start" button and type "cmd" into the search text box. Press "Enter" to open your Windows command line.
- Type "openssl /?" to view a list of options for the command line utility. This also shows you the proper syntax for the command.
- Type "openssl version" and press "Enter." The OpenSSL version is displayed in the Windows command line utility.

If the openssl command returns an error, it's probably not installed.

Comment: In between there is Apache.. When I try to launch OPENSSL I had the usual message "not recognized command" so probably it is not installed..

Comment: If you are the sysadmin for this server, if you installed Tomcat and not OpenSSL, I am pretty sure that it's not installed. And if you decide to install it now, you will have the patched version. Besides that - if you want to check for the heartbleed vulnerability, and if the Tomcat server is available via internet, you can do the test. Otherwise, you can try the Heartbleed Python script locally, if you have Python installed.

Comment: If you use Apache inbetween, than Tomcat probably does not connect via SSL, unless you use SSL between Apache and Tomcat, which is unusual. So if you want to use SSL you probably want to set this up for Apache. If you don't use Apache for other applications (like PHP webapps), you could do without and setup Tomcat to use port 80 instead of 8080. In that case you would setup Tomcat to use SSL directly.

Comment: OpenSSL is not part of Tomcat, **but the OpenSSL library is included in the Tomcat 6 windows binary packages** available from apache.org. The library code is integrated into a Tomcat dll, there is no `openssl.exe` included.

Answer (score 2):

There are several common modes of deployment for Tomcat on MS-Windows if HTTPS is enabled:

1. Tomcat running behind IIS, OpenSSL is not used
2. Tomcat running behind Apache, *OpenSSL is that used by Apache*
3. Tomcat standalone server with JSSE connector (Java SSL), OpenSSL is not used
4. Tomcat standalone server with APR connector, *OpenSSL in use*

If you have a standalone Tomcat server you can determine which HTTPS method is used by [inspecting the Connector protocol configuration](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File). The Apache provided Tomcat 6.0 binaries include APR (and hence OpenSSL) by default, though you may not be using it (upgrade anyway!). Further, if you have OpenSSL installed separately, it's irrelevant from Tomcat's point of view (though it *might* be used by your Apache or other web server).

If you are using an official (contrib) Apache-2.2 web server binary, the OpenSSL version number is typically encoded in the installer package file name. For 2.4 there are several different packaged versions. At least one (Apachehaus) documents the OpenSSL version *and* provide an `openssl.exe` you can run, though it may not be in the normal user `PATH` it's in the `bin/` subdirectory of the Apache installation.

If you have LogLevel of "info" or higher, Apache will log the mod_ssl and OpenSSL versions on startup. Since 6.0.36, Tomcat6 does the same ([bug #53057](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53057)).

To peek at what DLLs a running process has loaded [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) is handy, sadly though it appears that the normal Tomcat binary distribution link OpenSSL (and more) into a single DLL (`tcnative-1.dll`) rather than an easily identifiable (and replaceable) `libssl.dll`/`libcrypto.dll` (or similar) as is the convention on *nix systems. (This analysis will work on the Apachehaus Apache httpd though.)

A fairly primitive but reliable way then is to use `find` (or [strings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx) if you have it already), from a `cmd` prompt:

```
cd \Program Files\apache-tomcat\bin
find "OpenSSL" tcnative-1.dll
[...]
TLSv1 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1d 5 Feb 2013
SSLv3 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1d 5 Feb 2013
SSLv2 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1d 5 Feb 2013
DTLSv1 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1d 5 Feb 2013
```

Process Explorer will tell you the location of `tcnative-1.dll` for a running tomcat6 process if you cannot find it easily.

To summarise:

- check `netstat -abn -p TCP` to see what's listening on 443 (or whatever HTTPS port you use)
- check your connector to see if, and how, Tomcat provides SSL
- check your webserver version and HTTPS configuration